# How do I use a header only library with Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3pp (https://github.com/iwongu/sqlite3pp) with my project.

The folder has contents like:

```
sqlite3pp.h
sqlite3pp.ipp
sqlite3ppext.h
sqlite3ppext.ipp
```

There's also a src folder with .h and .cpp files.

Do I just include .h and .ipp files like we do with .h/.cpp files? If, yes, where do I put the .ipp files? Or do I need to compile it into a library?

Comment: You include the `.h` file, not the `.ipp` file.

Comment: @tkausl what about .ipp files? Should I just include them using normal flow(view solution explorer-> add existing files -> add .ipp and .h files here)?

Comment: If you take a quick look at the source, you'll see that the `.h` files already include the `.ipp` files. The structure should be as in the repository.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried doing including the headers, but I get 'cannot open file error'.

Comment: You need to add their folder to your include directories.

Comment: @molbdnilo I already did that. Should I try and include .ipp files as lib dependencies? I'll try and report back.

Comment: @molbdnilo That worked, just had to modify the lib path a bit. I cannot thank you enough! :)